# ElasticSearch indexed document not returned immediately

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES as backend. So, my architecture is based on a client-server.

Very often, maybe too much, I'm realizing when I perform two operations from client: `index` and `search` almost one after the other, the document indexed is not returned by ES.

When I refresh the result, the last indexed document is obtained from server.

Should I take something in mind in order to avoid this behavior?

Is this behavior something usual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is usual behaviour. ElasticSearch refreshes shard every 1 second.
ElasticSearch could work really slow if you refresh it after every index.

Comment: What about if I've a index-per-user? So, each index would be relativly small and would gather less index operations...

Comment: I think it is a bad idea. You could have a problem with big amount of segments. You could read it in more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/merge-process.html)